# Restriction of a monotone self-map ("endomorphism of $\mathbf{Pos}$") to a wide subposet

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders

Here's a poset, call it $P.$

$\hspace{1cm}$ [image: a poset]

Define a function $S : P \rightarrow P$ as follows.

$$S(0) = 1, \qquad S(1) = 2, \qquad S(2) = 2$$

Clearly, $S$ is monotone. Now consider the following subposets of $P$, all of which are [wide](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/wide+subcategory) but not [full](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/full+subcategory):

[image]

Observe that $S$ restricts to a monotone self-map on both $A$ and $B$, but not on $C$.

> **Question.** Under what conditions can we expect a monotone mapping $f : P^n \rightarrow P$ to restrict to a monotone mapping $S^n \rightarrow S$, where $S$ is a wide-but-not-full subposet of $P$?
>
> I'm most interested in the case where $P$ is a meet-semilattice, $S$ is a wide-but-not-full subposet of $P$ that isn't a sub-meet-semilattice, and $f$ is the meet operation $\wedge : P^2 \rightarrow P$. I haven't had much success understanding even the basics of this question; I **think** the meet restricts to a monotone mapping on each of $A,B$ and $C$ above, and I haven't been able to cook up a situation where it clearly doesn't restrict to a monotone mapping.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're using "wide" in the category-theoretic sense, in that all of our original poset elements are in the subposet, and "not full" in the same sense, that all some original comparisons must be excluded? I ask because I went to look up "wide" for posets, and realized it probably wasn't a poset-specific terminology.

Comment: @pjs36, yep, that's right. I find that the terminology for order-theory is a little under-developed, so I often just borrow terminology from category theory.

Comment: I think you won't find the answer in order theory because what you call "wide subposets" are not actually subposets. You should probably think about the problem in terms of directed graphs, removing edges, and probably graph homomorphisms.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff, thanks for your input, however I think that's just a terminological thing. Note that a wide-subposet of $P$ is basically just a monotone bijection $f : Q \rightarrow P$. So the concept *does* live comfortably in the world of order-theory, even if there is a bit of a terminological conflict. You make a good point about graph theory potentially being a good lead.

Comment: Well, should you pursue the latter venue, the notion you actually want is [weak homorphism, aka egamorphism](https://books.google.com/books?id=1Xtwgg-iYZ0C&pg=PA8), which can kill edges that map to the same vertex.

Comment: N.B.: you were right that notion of "wide subposet" exists in order theory as well. It's called a [refinement](https://books.google.com/books?id=-A3sbo0ZUKcC&pg=PA243). To be more precise, refinement is the opposite notion, if Q is a wide subposet of P, then P is a refinement of Q.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff, thanks for the info bud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a unary function $S: P\to P$, the only wide subposets of $P$ in which $S$ is still monotone are those made with following rule: if you remove an arrow from $P$, you must remove the corresponding arrow(s) from $S^{-1}(P)$. In your example, the preimage of the arrow $1 \to 2$ via $S$ is the arrow $0 \to 1$. So when you remove $1 \to 2$, $S$ remains montone if and only if you remove $0 \to 1$. That's why $S$ is monotone on $A$ but not on $C$. Since nothing maps to $0$ via $S$, that explains why you can remove the arrow $0 \to 1$ without removing anything else.

Note that you may need to remove more than one arrow as a consequence of the removal of a given arrow to preserve monotonicity. For example, with the order $0 < 1 < 2$ and $0' < 1$ (but $0$ and $0'$ incomparable), a monotone function $S'$ can map both $0$ and $0'$ to $1$ and $1 \mapsto 2, 2\mapsto 2$. In this example, when you remove the arrow $1 \to 2$, you have to remove both $0\to 1$ and $0'\to 1$ to preserve monotonicity of $S'$. The preimage of $1\to 2$ via $S'$ consists of both these arrows.

I have yet to think about the $n$-ary function case in full generality, but the above is enough to construct a counter-example for the semilattice & meet case. I assume you consider an *n*-ary function monotone by ordering its tuple argument such that $(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \le (b_1, \ldots, b_n)$ iff $a_i \le b_i, \forall i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Now consider the "rhombus" [semil]attice given by $0<1<2,\; 0<1'<2$. The monotonic unary function is going to be the meet with the fixed element $1$, i.e. $f(x)=1\wedge x$; it maps the arrow $1'\to 2$ to the arrow $0 \to 1$, so if we remove only the arrow $0 \to 1$ from this [semi]lattice, then $f$ is not monotone on the resulting poset $1<2,\; 0<1'<2$ (which is not a meet-semilattice) because $f(1')=0$ and $f(2) = 1$, but $0$ and $1$ are incomparable in the discompleted rhombus.

Comment: Regarding the penultimate paragraph; yes, that I what I mean by saying that an $n$-ary function is monotone. Note that this is (rather amazingly) equivalent to requiring that it be monotone separately in each argument.

Comment: @goblin: Well, that seems to be the whole point of defining _n_-ary monotonicity like that. [Some](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.50.9848&rep=rep1&type=pdf) even take the latter/property as the definition.

Comment: @goblin: Also, this order on tuples is sometimes called the [product order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_order). Not surprisingly it's the [categorical] product in the category of posets and monotone functions.

Comment: But it *is* surprising though. Think vector spaces. Are bilinear maps $X,Y \rightarrow Z$ necessarily linear maps $X \times Y \rightarrow Z$? No. Does the converse hold? No again. There's something very special about posets....